# Prove that $o(g(n)) \cap \omega(g(n))$ is the empty set

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

This question is from CLRS (3rd Edition).

So, I know that this is true, but I can't seem to prove it.
My approach was the following:

Let $f(n) = o(g(n)) \Rightarrow 0 \le f(n)  < c_2g(n)$ for some $c_2 > 0$ and for all $n \ge n_1 \ge 0$

Similarly, $f(n) = \omega(g(n)) \Rightarrow 0 \le c_1g(n)  < f(n)$ for some $c_1 > 0$ and for all $n \ge n_2 \ge 0 $

Therefore, $0 \le c_1g(n) < f(n) < c_2 g(n)$

But this can be true for $f(n) = 2n$ and $g(n) = n$ and $c_1 = 1$, $c_2 = 3$, and $n_1 = n_2 = 1$

So what exactly am I not picking up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is your definition of $o$ and $\omega$.

$f\in o(g)$ if and only if $f(n) = h(n)g(n)$ with $h(n) \underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$.

$f\in \omega(g)$ if and only if $g\in o(f)$.

What you used as definition are $\mathcal{O}$ and $\Omega$ (which are different).

Comment: The definition I used are given in CLRS. [o-notation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xp8UFsMXInfEhMVid4dbYvEhdLquTnDS/view?usp=share_link) and [ω-notation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13GN2Jm7GSJidaTCwNJvKtV-gdH46w7Bx/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: In this definition, the property $f(n) < c g(n)$ must be true for **ANY** $c>0$, not for **SOME** $c>0$. The quantification is universal, not existential.